# ubuntu reboot failed

Tags: boot

I'm a newbie in using ubuntu. Yesterday I was installing a few packages. During the process, at certain point the sudo command did not work anymore. So I rebooted, and it just stuck at booting page. I tried to search solutions online, got into recovery mode, tried a few things. Nothing works. Now when I reboot, I get error messages saying 
"Failed to sart Network Manager.
Failed to start login servcice. "

I don't want to reinstall the system. What can I do now?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: What does "the sudo command did not work anymore" mean? What were you doing, *exactly*? Don't make potential helpers guess - they likely won't bother.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for trying to help!
I don't remember exactly what was prompted at first. When I went to recovery mode, using sudo command gave:
sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

I have no idea of what going on. But I did find a solution from a youtube clip.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y9QxdiqWyjs
Basically, it's running a few commands as follows.
/sbin/fsck -fy
/sbin/mount -wu /
/bin/chmod 1775 /
/bin/sync
exit

Some of them didn't work. Some worked. At the end, I can log back in again without knowing what happened...